# BLDC 3 phases low side current sensing

Tags: current-measurement, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

Hello I'm struggling with calculation of BLDC motor current. I'm using MP6540 driver for controlling BLDC. I can measure voltage (adc) and after using appropriate formula from datasheet I got current results in all 3 phases. But I'm not sure that results are fine. Adc give new voltage every ~714nS. My question is what I missing, how to calculate current of the BLDC motor when I have 3 reading from 3 phases? I need idea how to calculate current in BLDC motor when I have 3 reading from 3 phases general. Any idea is welcome

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You do need to set an ISR for each analog input. The correct timing sequence is subject to PWM pulse driving sequence, amplifier settling time, analog input settling time, sample/hold settling time,...

You may find some articles from STM32, TI, Freescale, using SPWM and similar modulation, when exactly you should take samples, also formulas for computing phase currents.

[TI example FOC - (not six step BLDC !!)](https://www.tij.co.jp/lit/pdf/tiducy7)

[Freescale example FOC](https://www.nxp.com/files/32bit/doc/brochure/BB3PHCRMSRART.pdf)

[STM32 example FOC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/cd00298474-stm32f-pmsm-singledual-foc-sdk-v43-stmicroelectronics.pdf) 
[image]

[Microchip FOC phase currents measurement](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/appnotes/01299a.pdf)
[image]

If you have a six step commutation, then only one upper and one lower transistor is conducting. 1st ISR is starts when both transistors are on, this enables 2nd ISR a delay time, so that current and amplifier have settled, at 2nd ISR you do take a sample from corresponding phase ADC, this enables the 3rd ISR - conversion end. At 3rd ISR the conversion is finished and you store the value.

Comment: After researching on internet I find that FOC is much better then just 6 phases commutation, so your advice is to learn FOC algorithm for controlling BLDC?